# Boot Linux to ram-only, one time user on a second partition

Tags: linux, multi-boot, ramdisk

I am looking to setup a laptop I use for work as follows. One partition with a Linux install (Backtrack) with tools, normal write, etc. I want to create a second partition with a one-time use setup; i.e., its regular unbuntu or something that I can use for email, youtube, etc that when I kill the power everything is lost. Ideally, I could also boot the onetime use partition in write mode to make changes or upgrades, but in general I want to keep everything isolated. I do not want to use a USB or live disc.

How should I go about this setup, and is there anything else I should consider? Maybe a third partition to save files off when absolutely necessary?

I also want to ensure that the Backtrack partition is encrypted to protect client data. I wouldn't imagine that would cause any issues here, but thought I should ask.

Comment: I read through this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM, but I don't quite think this is what I want, is it?

Comment: Something similar to what you're asking for is done with Linux on embedded systems and LiveCDs: the root filesystem, initramfs, is mounted on *ramfs*, which is filled in with a compressed *cpio* image.  Note that *ramfs* is not just a *RAM disk*; an ordinary *RAM disk* will require a fixed memory allocation, whereas a *ramfs* will grow or shrink as needed.  Check out the Buildroot project for compiling a kernel and small-footprint rootfs.